# Why are really old posts showing up? Is this normal?

Tags: support, recent-activity

I've been noticing some posts floating up to the top that don't appear to have had any activity in *years*. For example, here's one, whose latest activity was an edit in 2014 (yes, before you ask, all the answers and comments are contained in the screenshot):

[image: old post]
[how to properly install ubuntu on imac? (bootcamp)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295414/how-to-properly-install-ubuntu-on-imac-bootcamp)

Is this expected behavior? Are posts like this floating to the top because they don't have an accepted answer yet? Am I missing something obvious? Or is there some other explanation?

Thanks for any info about this! I'm enjoying my time here so far. I can't wait to get to 2000 reputation :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An automatic process called [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738) randomly pokes old questions where an answer exists but hasn't been evaluated (has 0 score and is not accepted). The exact criteria are [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511).

As I wrote [elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278820),

> The reason is "this question may already have an answer that hasn't been recognized as such". It's brought forward so a decision can be made: there is a decent answer (voted up) or no, the attempted answer isn't useful (voted down).

Comment: That explains it. Thank you!